# Display images from documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory, aqgridview

I'm using the following method to display images in an AQGridview:

DataModel.m:

```
-(id)initWithCaption:(NSString*)theCaption andImage:(UIImage*)theImage andURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)theURLRequest
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.caption = theCaption;
        self.image = theImage;
        self.myURLRequest = theURLRequest;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then:

```
DataModel *appService = [[AppsDocumentService alloc] initWithCaption:theAppName andImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconIdentifier] andURLRequest:requestObject];
```

Where `iconIdentifier` is a string matching an image in the app's Supporting files folder, e.g. `@"Icon.png"`

It works but only with images stored in Supporting files / Xcode project folder and I'd like to be able to display images from the app's documents directory.

I tried some variations along the lines of:

```
iconIdentifier = @"/var/mobile/Applications/28CC364F-0895-4556-9F58-DAB5AB9104A7/Documents/downloads/AppIcons/Icon.png";
```

but that isn't working.

I was hoping someone could tell me if there's a way to modify what I already have to display images from the documents directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks - figured it out almost as soon as I posted the question

Instead of:

```
initWithCaption:theAppName andImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconIdentifier] andURLRequest:requestObject];
```

I needed:

```
initWithCaption:theAppName andImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:iconIdentifier]] andURLRequest:requestObject];
```